# Ng-Repeat ng-show if previous item field value different

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

If have a list of items with date field which is ordered by date. I want to group these items by date somethings like;

### Date1

- item1

### Date2

- item2
- item3

and so forth...

What I have is this;

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="listing in listings | filter:query">
        <h1 ng-show="$index === 0 || listings[$index - 1].created !== listing.created">
            {{listing.created | date:mediumDate}}
        </h1>
        {{listing.title}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

But this way h1 element becomes the child of li element which messes up presentation. Is there some other way to write this ng-repeat the way I want?

Comment: Can you re-organize your data/model object so that this hierarchy is represented as an array of objects that each has an array?  If you do it this way you can nest the ng-repeats.  You can apply the first ng-repeat to a div that wraps the date header and list, then use the second ng-repeat on the li within a list.

Comment: I am using flask-restless on the server side, so I guess no. I can do that arrangement in the controller but I am using infinite scroll and rearranging the object array all the time didn't seem very elegant. But so far this seems like the only solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a solution that might not work depending on the number of items in your list.

My idea was to apply a filter to transform a simple list into a hierarchical one.

<strike>Here's a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xSptw/1/).</strike>  (See the new one at the bottom, really!)

The idea is simple, take an existing list, and rearrange it on-the-fly:

```html
<div ng-repeat="g in items | groupBy:'group' | orderBy:'group'">
    <h2>{{g.group}}</h2>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in g.items | orderBy:'title'">{{item.id}}. {{item.title}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In this case, we've take the original array, and applied a `groupBy` filter on it.  This filter is actually sort of complex, because it needs to make sure it doesn't modify the array more than necessary, so it has to store a **deep copy** of the original array to compare against.  If you remove that deep copy and inspection, you will end up with `$digest` iteration errors every time.

> **Edit:** See bottom for a modified version that performs shallower copies of the array

Here's the filter code:

```js
app.filter("groupBy", function() {
    var mArr = null,
        mGroupBy = null,
        mRetArr = null;
    return function(arr, groupBy) {
        if(!angular.equals(mArr, arr) || mGroupBy !== groupBy) {
            mArr = angular.copy(arr);
            mGroupBy = groupBy;
            mRetArr = [];
            var groups = {};
            angular.forEach(arr, function(item) {
                var groupValue = item[groupBy]
                if(groups[groupValue]) {
                    groups[groupValue].items.push(item);
                } else {
                    groups[groupValue] = {
                        items: [item]
                    };
                    groups[groupValue][groupBy] = groupValue;
                    mRetArr.push(groups[groupValue]);
                }
            });
        }
        return mRetArr;
    };
});
```

(`mArr`, `mGroupBy`, and `mRetArr` are the "memoized" values, here.)

What's nice about this filter is that it doesn't *require* that the data come in already grouped.  The jsFiddle linked above include a button to dynamically add items to the array at the end, but they still end up sorted into groups.

Again, the real caveat is that it could be slow and/or expensive based on the number of items in your list.  Hundreds of moderately-complex items should be OK, but if you have thousands, you should pre-sort them somewhere else before they get to the scope.

---

## Edit: Much better version

At the cost of more code complexity, I modified the filter to copy only the key information instead of deeply copying the whole array.  This time, I make a hashmap of the groups containing the items.  The items are still referenced, but this time it's an explicit reference, so modifying an item in the tree will not force a resort, but changing an item's group or adding or removing an item will.

**New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hhWaX/2/**

And here's the new filter:

```js
app.filter("groupBy", function() {
    var mArr = null,
        mGroupBy = null,
        mRetArr = null,
        getMemoArr = function(arr, groupBy) {
            var ret = {};
            angular.forEach(arr, function(item){
                var groupValue = item[groupBy];
                if(ret[groupValue]) {
                    ret[groupValue].push(item);
                } else {
                    ret[groupValue] = [item];
                }
            });
            return ret;
        };
    return function(arr, groupBy) {
        var newMemoArr = getMemoArr(arr, groupBy);
        if(mGroupBy !== groupBy || !angular.equals(mArr, newMemoArr)) {
            mArr = newMemoArr;
            mGroupBy = groupBy;
            mRetArr = [];
            var groups = {};
            angular.forEach(arr, function(item) {
                var groupValue = item[groupBy]
                if(groups[groupValue]) {
                    groups[groupValue].items.push(item);
                } else {
                    groups[groupValue] = {
                        items: [item]
                    };
                    groups[groupValue][groupBy] = groupValue;
                    mRetArr.push(groups[groupValue]);
                }
            });
        }
        return mRetArr;
    };
});
```

It's a lot more complicated, but this one should have significantly better performance over large sets, because there is the absolute minimum of duplication of the original array.

Comment: In theory, if you knew the `group` would never change for any of the items, you could replace the deep copy (`angular.copy(...)`) with a shallow copy that only copied over the items themselves.  There may be some magical way to store the items along with their original groups, too.

Comment: And, for the hell of it, here's a version that can take a function to determine the groupBy value: http://jsfiddle.net/9dpN2/1/

Comment: I just realized I made the memoization global by accident.  I think.  If I am correct, then using this filter twice within the same app/module may not work.  It's too late, I'll think about later!

Comment: Great answer ty. And thanks for the bonus groupBy that can take a function.

Answer (score 2):

```
<li class="divider" ng-if="FormsList[$index].FORM_GROUP!=FormsList[$index-1].FORM_GROUP">
```

Works perfectly for me. like this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Form..." ng-model="selectedForm">

<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" role="menu" ng-repeat="Form in FormsList | filter:selectedForm">
    <li class="divider" ng-if="FormsList[$index].FORM_GROUP!=FormsList[$index-1].FORM_GROUP">{{Form.FORM_GROUP}}</li>
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="LoadPDF(Form.LOCATION)">{{Form.LINK}}</a></li>
</ul>
```